# How to using column data from query as row in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, oracle, datagridview

Hello guys(sorry my english, isn't pretty good)

I have a query with 3 columns that bring data from Oracle database and I want to use one of these columns as row in datagridview.

It's like columns "name", "date" and "count of names" and the "date" column have to be a row  in datagrid and below come the rest as column.

Anybody know how I can do this in c#? 
I'm making a winform application.

I make myself clear? If anyone don't understand me, just let me know than I try to explain again.

Here is the query from Oracle.

```html
SELECT UPPER(U.NOME) INTEGRANTE, 
 TO_CHAR(TRUNC(L.DATALOG), 'dd/mm/yyyy') DATALOG,
  count(U.NOME) TOTAL
  FROM rastreabilidade.LOGPROCESSO L, 
  rastreabilidade.SITUACAO S, 
  rastreabilidade.USUARIO U, 
  rastreabilidade.PERFIL P,
  rastreabilidade.documento doc,  
  rastreabilidade.subtipodocumento std,
  rastreabilidade.tipodocumento td, 
  rastreabilidade.unidade un
WHERE TRUNC(L.DATALOG) BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-02-2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY')AND TO_DATE('27-02-2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND L.SITUACAOID NOT IN ('0') 
  AND L.SITUACAOID = S.SITUACAOID 
  AND L.USUARIOID = U.USUARIOID 
  AND U.PERFILID = P.PERFILID 
  AND L.DOCUMENTOID = DOC.DOCUMENTOID 
  AND DOC.TIPODOCUMENTOID = TD.TIPODOCUMENTOID 
  AND DOC.SUBTIPODOCUMENTOID = STD.SUBTIPODOCUMENTOID
  AND DOC.UNIDADEID = UN.UNIDADEID
  AND P.PERFILID IN ('786','10000','10001','10002','3070')
  GROUP BY UPPER(U.NOME), TO_CHAR(TRUNC(L.DATALOG), 'dd/mm/yyyy')
  ORDER BY TO_CHAR(TRUNC(L.DATALOG), 'dd/mm/yyyy').
```

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like you need to pivot your data. This can be done in Oracle query or in C#. Can you prepare simplified desired output in table form and query if possible?

Comment: I think that Pivot solve my problem, but unfortunatelly, my oracle version is 10 g.

Comment: Look at link in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have data like in my first table and want something like second table?

```
You have this:                      ... and you want this:
INTEGRANTE DATALOG     TOTAL  |     INTEGRANTE  04/03/2015  20/02/2015  27/02/2015
BOB        04/03/2015     11  |     GEORGE               7           9           8
BOB        20/02/2015      3  |     BOB                 11           3           2
BOB        27/02/2015      2  |     MARY                 4           6           5
GEORGE     04/03/2015      7  |
GEORGE     20/02/2015      9  |
GEORGE     27/02/2015      8  |
MARY       04/03/2015      4  |
MARY       20/02/2015      6  |
MARY       27/02/2015      5  |
```

If so, then you can build SQL query in C# code, similiar to query below, with simple `foreach loop`, with dates given in your period. 
It is not super elegant solution, but should work.

Important! This requires Oracle 11g or later. For older version you need to build something like in [this article](http://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php), look for words "Prior to 11 g..."

```
with YOUR_QUERY as (
  /*YOUR QUERY GOES HERE*/        -- <-- put your actual query here
  )
select * 
  from YOUR_QUERY        
  pivot (sum(total) for (datalog) in (
    '04/03/2015' as "04/03/2015", -- <-- 
    '20/02/2015' as "20/02/2015", -- <-- BUILD THESE LINES IN C# LOOP
    '27/02/2015' as "27/02/2015"  -- <--
    ) )
```

BTW: you should edit your original question, instead of posting answer, but I understand your technical problems ;-) Please read help pages on this site.

Comment: Thanks Ponder Stibbons,

Unfortunatelly my oracle is 10g , I will look this article That You put for older version , but is exactly like your second table that I need .

I will build in C # and  if works, I answer here .

Thank you again .